# add css to jquery .html() load

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

hi i have bit of working jquery code that is:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#createaccount").submit(function(e){
    var fname = $("#fname").val();
    var surname = $("#surname").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var location = $("#location").val();
    var username = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    var re_pass = $("#re_password").val();

    var valid = true;

    if(fname == ""){
        $("#fnameerror").html('<span class="errortext">Please enter your first name</span>');
        valid = false;
    }

    if(surname == ""){
        $("#surnameerror").html('<span class="errortext">Please enter your surname</span>');
        valid = false;

    }

    if(email == ""){
        $("#emailerror").html('<span class="errortext">Please enter an email address</span>');
        valid = false;

    }
    else{
        var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
        if(reg.test(email)==false){
            $("#emailerror").html('<span class="errortext">The email address is invalid</span>');
            valid = false;
        }
    }

    if(location == ""){
        $("#locationerror").html('<span class="errortext">Please enter your location</span>');
        valid = false;
    }

    if(username == ""){
        $("#usernameerror").html('<span class="errortext">Please enter a username</span>');
        valid = false;
    }
    else{
        if(username.length < 6){
            $("#usernameerror").html('<span class="errortext">Username must be at least 6 characters long</span>');
            valid = false;
        }
    }

    if(password == ""){
        $("#passworderror").html('<span class="errortext">Please enter a password</span>');
        valid = false;
    }
    else{
        if(password.length < 6){
            $("#passworderror").html('<span class="errortext">Password must be at least 6 characters long</span>');
            valid = false;
        }
    }

    if(re_pass == ""){
        $("#re_passerror").html('<span class="errortext">Please re-enter your password</span>');
        valid = false;
    }
    else{
        if(re_pass != password){
            $("#re_passerror").html('<span class="errortext">The passwords do not match</span>');
            valid = false;
        }
    }

    if(valid == false){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'createaccount2.php',
            data: $("#createaccount").serialize(),
            success: function(response){

                if(response == "1"){
                    $("#response").html('<span class="responsefail">Your username has already been taken, please enter another</span>');
                }
                else if(response == "2"){
                    $("#response").html('<span class="responsefail">An account is already registered to that email</span>');
                }
                else if(response == "3"){
                    $("#response").html('<span class="responsegood">Your account has been created!</span>');
                    $("#redirect").html('<span class="redirect">Click</span><a class="redirectlink" href="divbayindex.htm">HERE</a><span class="redirect"> to return to the DiveBay homepage</span>');
                }
                else if(response == "4"){
                    $("#response").html('<span class="responsefail">Something went wrong, your account could not be created, please try again in a moment</span>');
                    $("#redirect").html('<span class="redirect">Click</span><a class="redirectlink" href="divbayindex.htm">HERE</a><span class="redirect"> to return to the DiveBay homepage</span>');

                }
            }

        });
    e.preventDefault();
    }
    });





});
```

im just wondering how to add style to this span. ive included the css for these span classes in the original page's css file, but when this span gets loaded by the function it appears as it would if default.

i have a similar problem for another page where i load a table of search results and it only appears as default. i figure its something to do with the external css reference?

Comment: Any existing CSS will apply to DOM-inserted content provided there are matching rules. Use something like Firebug or Dragonfly to inspect the inserted spans to try to see why these rules are not attaching themselves to these elements. There is no reason they shouldn't if the rules match.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS rules should apply to all elements on screen, not just the ones that were there when the page was first loaded. I would check the css selectors to make sure that they match the class name(, make sure you remembered the . before the class)

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to do anything specific to make the CSS apply to the created span. Just style it as you would with any other class, for example:

```
.redirect {
  color: #EEE;
  font-size: 15px;  
}

.responsefail {
  color: #FF0000;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

The style for these classes will then load with the freshly inserted elements even though the stylesheet were loaded before they were even created.

If you'd however prefer to add the css with jquery, you could just go ahead and add

```
$('.yourclass').css('attribute', 'value');
```

in each if-action.

***If this doesn't help you further, please provide the html code for the page.***